# mySQL `date_updated` column only for specific fields: SELECT and INSERT vs TRIGGER?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I have a bunch of resources that are stored in a MySQL db.

Each have a `date_modified` field that was set to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

however, there are now columns on those tables that we DON'T want to trigger the `date_modified`.

From what I can see there are 2 options. (excluding refactoring the tables)

1) Before the update, load the current entity back from the DB, check if the fields have changed, and set the `date_modified` based on that.

2) Create a `TRIGGER` for each table that will check the `NEW` fields against the `OLD` fields and set the time stamp.

I'm torn between the two approaches.

1 will have a bigger overhead, as it has to perform 2 queries.

2 helps maintain data integrity, but potentially could cause issues later as it masks some of the application logic. If a new field is added at a later date, the dev will have to remember to also update the trigger to to ensure it updates the modified column.

Is there a third approach?  Somehow in the UPDATE check if the values have changed and then update the date_modified?

Or any other ways to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

There's a third choice.  Mention the `date_modified` column in the `UPDATE` query.

For example,

```
  UPDATE some_table
     SET some_column = 'new value',
         date_modified = date_modified
   WHERE id = some_id_value
```

This will change the row in the table while preserving the date_modified value.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I have just been playing with.  I was actually approaching it from the other direction - remove the auto time stamp, and then check if the fields have changed in the SET statement.... something like....    `SET date_modified = CASE
 WHEN ( a!='1' OR b!='2' OR c!='3' ) THEN NOW()
 ELSE date_modified
END`

Comment: but that adds a lot more complexity, and Id rather keep it simple!